# How to lookup multiple columns in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

As the attached image, I can use the lookup formula to find out "Mary" by the value "D", however, is there any way I can also find out "Mary" by the value of "J", "P" or "V"?

[image: lookup]

Comment: When you get answers, you should decide and mark them as answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use INDEX MATCH based approach like this:

```
=INDEX(G1:G6,SUM((H1:L6=D1)*ROW(H1:L6)))
```

If you have a version of Excel older than 2016, you will have to enter this formula with CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER.

[image]

> NOTE - this only works if the table starts in row 1.

So to make it more general, you could do:

```
=INDEX(G1:G6,SUM((H1:L6=D1)*(ROW(H1:L6)-ROW(H1)+1)))
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, the problem has been solved by your formula.

Comment: @MissMan - cool - can you please mark it as the answer?

Comment: `=INDEX(G1:G6,AGGREGATE(15,6,1/COUNTIF(D1,H1:L6)*ROW(H1:L6),SEQUENCE(SUMPRODUCT(--(D1=H1:L6)))))` spills the result in case of multiple matches.

Comment: @P.b - nice work. Out of the box thinking too. I think this OP has gotten the free work and bailed. This happens 4 out of 5 times. I usually circle back to see if they ever decide an answer (no matter who provides it) and, if not, downvote. Anymore, I am reticent to answer questions from ppl with 1 point - waste of time.

Comment: Yeah, maybe it'll help future visitors though. (And I like exploring possibilities and keep learning here. I wouldn't have thought of possibly using SUM in this case for instance. I would've thought in the corner of COUNTIF or SEARCH only.

Answer (score 2):

Another shorter option, can return single or multiple match.

In `D2`, enter formula :

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",,IF(H1:L6=D1,G1:G6,""))
```

For Excel 2019, It will have to enter this formula with CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER.

For Office 365, it will normal entry.

[image]

Comment: Love this solution.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `Lookup`, but `VLookup`, let me show you:

```
=VLOOKUP(D4,$D$4:$H$20,2,FALSE)
```

This means (in case "Mary" is put in cell D4): go look in to D4:H20 (made invariable using the dollar signs), and take the second column (containing the "D") variable.

If you want to find "J" (third column), use:

```
=VLOOKUP(D4,$D$4:$H$4,3,FALSE)
```

If you want to find "P" (fourth column):

```
=VLOOKUP(D4,$D$4:$H$4,4,FALSE)
```

The last parameter is just for having an exact search.

Comment: That's not how VLOOKUP works. The number in the 3rd statement of the formula refers to the result column, not the search column. It always starts from the first column in given range.

Comment: It is, but I misread the question: I was using "Mary" to find "J" and "P", while the author wanted to use "J" and "P" to find "Mary". The best way to solve this issue is using `XLookup`, but I don't know how this works exactly.

Comment: An XLOOKUP is really just a VLOOKUP|HLOOKUP in an improved form. The VLOOKUP should be avoided where possible because it uses a column reference that could change. e.g. If I insert or delete a column, the VLOOKUP will deliver the wrong result (possibly undetected). This case needs to create a row index similar to MATCH, but the search array is two dimensional, thus a calc is needed to tease it out.