# Is there a Google Sheets (or Excel) formula like HLOOKUP() but that will search over a two-dimensional range, as opposed to a single row?

Tags: excel, if-statement, google-sheets, lambda, textjoin

I have a Google Sheets spreadsheet and I am hoping to write a formula that finds the location of a given phrase *anywhere* in the spreadsheet and then returns the value of the cell a certain number of cells below the searched-for cell. For example, if I am searching for the value "11/15/2022", and that cell is C4, I would want to return the value of cell C6. I have tried using `HLOOKUP()`, but that limits my search range to a single row, and I need to be able to search anywhere in the spreadsheet (and the data has dimensions that are both greater than one).

Is there a function (either Excel or Google Sheets) that will perform this? Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try:

```
=INDEX(TEXTJOIN(, 1, IF(B1:F10=A1, B3:F12, )))
```

[image]

Comment: For Excel a similar idea also works. You can check the answer from @bosco_yip to this question: [How to lookup multiple columns in excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70922274/how-to-lookup-multiple-columns-in-excel). Great solution player0

Comment: Here is the corresponding Excel equivalent approach:`=LET(rng, B1:F10, TEXTJOIN(", ",,IF(rng=A1,IFERROR(OFFSET(rng, 2,0),"Out of range"),"")))`. Added a check for preventing out of range. Worth noticing that this kind of approach works only for **positive** offsets by row or column. If more than one result was found, it returns the result as comma separated values.

Answer (score 1):

For Excel, use the sample data provided by @Ping's answer. In cel `H2`, you can put the following formula:

```
=LET(rng, A1:E5, n, ROWS(rng), m, COLUMNS(rng), lookup, G1,rOffset, G2, cOffSet, G3, 
  match, IF(rng=lookup,1,0), NF, "Not Found",
  IF(MAX(match) = 0, NF, LET(rows, MAKEARRAY(n, m, LAMBDA(r,c,r)),
    cols, MAKEARRAY(n, m, LAMBDA(r,c,c)), found, MAP(rows, cols, match,
    LAMBDA(r,c,m, IF(m = 1,IFERROR(INDEX(rng,r + rOffset,c + cOffSet), NF),""))),
    TEXTSPLIT(TEXTJOIN(",",, found),, ",")))
)
```

and here is the corresponding output:
[image: sample excel file]

**Note**: This solution can find values backward by row and/or by column as well as forward (positive or negatives offset values for row and/or column). Because it finds the result first, then it returns the corresponding offset value.

`match` name is a `[0,1]` array of the same shape as `rng`, that is set to `1` if the `lookup` value was found, otherwise `0`.

We use `MAKEARRAY` to store rows and columns of `rng`. The names `rows`, `cols` are arrays of the same shape as `rng` having rows and columns respectively.

The name `found`:

```
MAP(rows, cols, match, LAMBDA(r,c,m, IF(m = 1,
  IFERROR(INDEX(rng,r + rOffset,c + cOffSet), NF),"")))
```

Returns an array of the same shape as `rng`, with empty cell where there is no match, or the corresponding value from `rng` considering row and column offset.

Now we just need to remove empty cells. We use `TEXTJOIN` for that. Finally, we use `TEXTSPLIT` to return the result in an array column format.

This approach considers the following non happy path scenarios. It returns `Not Found` (it can customized to a different value):

- The `lookup` value was not found
- The offset values produce a value out of the input range

Answer (score 0):

[image: sample]

Provide this code with your lookup value, row-offset and col-offset values in H1:H3,

lookup results will be shown in column K.

If there are more than one match with the lookup value, all results will be spill out into column K. (e.g, if there is 3 matches with the given lookup value, but after applying the offsets, there are more than 1 results value, all the unique results will be returned as an array in column K).

```
=LAMBDA(LOOKUPVALUE,ROWOFFSET,COLOFFSET,DATA,
 LAMBDA(ROWA,COLA,
  LAMBDA(COLLEN,ROWLEN,
   UNIQUE(FLATTEN(MAKEARRAY(ROWLEN,COLLEN,LAMBDA(ROW,COL,
    LAMBDA(CELLVALUE,
     IF(CELLVALUE=LOOKUPVALUE,INDEX(DATA,ROW+ROWOFFSET,COL+COLOFFSET),"")
    )(INDEX(DATA,ROW,COL))
   ))),FALSE,TRUE)
  )(COUNTBLANK(ROWA)+COUNTA(ROWA),COUNTBLANK(COLA)+COUNTA(COLA))
 )(INDEX(DATA,1),INDEX(DATA,,1))
)($H$1,$H$2,$H$3,$A$1:$F)
```